# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) - Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, command, ios-simulator

My app runs fine on a real device, but when i'm trying to run it on a simulator it gives me this error. Can anyone help me understand what's this error is ?

**ld: in'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib/libextension.dylib', missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib/libextension.dylib (3 slices) for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to link libextension.dylib against the *DEVICE* SDK rather than the *SIMULATOR* SDK.

You should make sure that you are linking against **/usr/lib/libextension.dylib** relative to the SDK rather than against /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib/libextension.dylib relative to /